# Error when fetching offline hexdocs for Elixir core & kernel

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I can run `mix hex.docs online timex` to open the latest online docs for the `timex` package, and I can run `mix hex.docs offline timex` to download a cache of those same `timex` docs and open them offline in the browser, which is super handy during flights etc.

Likewise, I can run `mix hex.docs online elixir` to open the latest online docs for the Elixir core library. But when I run `mix hex.docs offline elixir` (the offline equivalent), I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find docs for package with name elixir or version 1.13.3
```

Is this a bug? Or am I using the command incorrectly? What's the easiest way for me to cache and open an offline copy of the Elixir core hexdocs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
$ mix hex.docs offline elixir
Docs fetched: /Users/adam/.hex/docs/hexpm/elixir/1.14.2
```

Are you using the latest version of hex? Try `mix local.hex`.

Comment: Confirmed this works for elixir 1.13.3 too.

Comment: Works also with 1.12.2.

Comment: Ah ha! Updating hex did it. Thanks!